# Array replacing last value, not adding [PHP]

Tags: php, arrays, array-push

I have a PHP array, set up using

```
$this->cart = array();
```

Which is all ind and dandy except the array will not, no matter what i do, take new values, but only replaces the existing values with the new ones.

I've tried array_merge, array_push and others and the same thing happens but this is the code that *should* work.

```
$this->cart[]=$input;
```

The first time that is used, it say there's one item in the array "Array ( [0] => 1 "
The second time it's used it will show this, replacing the first value "Array ( [0] => 2 ) "

Adding values are triggered by a form with pulling the ID and putting it into the array as the value

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="addeditem" value="2">';
```

But no matter what code, it will not append the array, only replace it, any ideas. I have tried adding a key and value, as well as creating a second array and merging it in and nothing works.

The function to add to cart is this

```
function addToCart($input){
$this->cart[]=$input;
$this->setCartCount();
}
```

Solved: See comments.

Comment: Your array is probably being reset somewhere else.

Comment: Check if you don't re-create the array before you add the new item. Try to dump its value just before adding new item. Does it really have one item already?

Comment: Got it! Sam Dufel nailed it, somewhere in my testing i removed the array from sessions and onto the page, which reset it everytime it started. Post it as an answer and i'll check it off for you.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that $this->cart is a global variable and that the array isn't created every time you call addToCart() ?

Try sth. like this:

1. have a cart Object

   ```
   public class cart{

      private $items;
      function __construct() {
        $items=array();
      }
      public function addToCart($item){
        $this->items[]=$item;
      }
   }
   ```
2. Add the Item to the cart somewhere else in your code.

   ```
   $cart=$manager->getCart();
   $cart->addToCart($your_new_item);
   ```

Answer (score -1):

The name should be following : `addeditem[]`

Comment: Nah that's not it. $itemId = $_POST['addeditem']; and then runs this $ShoppingCart->addToCart($itemId);

Comment: This way $_POST['addeditem']; will be an array containing all of the hidden inputs' value